# Replacing full name with last name and initial with messy data

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I am working on a project involving presidential candidates and am struggling to clean the data due to the variations in the name spelling and abbreviations. For example, for Hillary Clinton, the data might include:

`"clinton", "clinton, hillary rodham", "clinton, hilary”, clinton, hil”`

Is there a way to convert all of the names into the format: last name, first initial? (i.e.: `clinton, h.`)

So far I have converted all of the entries to lowercase and have tried the following for replacement:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if ((df$can_name %like% c("clinton, hilary", "hillary", "clinton, hillary rodham", "clinton, hilary"))==TRUE){
  df$can_name <- ‘clinton, h.'
  }
}
```

However, I have over 100,000 observations, so this would get extremely tedious to do for every candidate. In the past I have used grep to split up and replace strings, but I am not sure how to deal with middle names and misspellings in this case. I am not very familiar with regex, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I ended up using a variation of Onyambu's answer. For my final solution, I decided to just use the candidates' last names and was able to replace multiple variations using the | (and) opperator. Here is the code:

```
sub(".*clinton.*|.*hilary.*|.*hillary.*", "clinton", df$can_name )
```

Comment: [Something like this](https://regex101.com/r/vVnCbI/2) might help. This of course supposes name is always before first name. Also I'm not familiar with the `r` language at all so sorry if that isn't compatible somehow.

Comment: There are several "Clinton" candidates; Hillary and Bill. Is your example only for a certain timeframe? If not, how will you handle "Bush" or "Clinton" candidates without a first name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub`.

```
   sub(".*Clinton.*","Clinton, h.", df$can_name)
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you did here? Specifically, what do the . and * symbols do?

Comment: it is a regular expression to capture everything before the word `Clinton` and after the word `Clinton`

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply functions. They are vectorized and offer much faster way of iterating. You can do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(vec = c('c','b','a','clinton', 'clinton, hillary rodham', 'clinton, hilary', 'clinton, hil'))

namesp <- c('clinton', 'clinton, hillary rodham', 'clinton, hilary', 'clinton, hil')

df$can_name <- sapply(df$vec, function(x) if(x %in% namesp) return('clinton, h.') else return('not found'))
print(df)

                       vec    can_name
1:                       c   not found
2:                       b   not found
3:                       a   not found
4:                 clinton clinton, h.
5: clinton, hillary rodham clinton, h.
6:         clinton, hilary clinton, h.
7:            clinton, hil clinton, h.
```

Answer (score 1):

Save time by creating a "lookup table" with perfect data and merging it by an easily extracted field in your main (messy) dataframe.

```
# Your Main Data (dirty)
df <- tibble(name = c("clinton", 
                "clinton, hillary rodham",
                "clinton, hillary",
                "clinton, hil") )

# Your Perfect Lookup Data 
lookup_table <- tibble(
      first_name = "Hillary",
      middle_name = "Rodham",
      last_name = "Clinton")
```

Extract something easy from your main data and merge. Always good practice to keep your "raw" data column to spot check for errors.

```
my.regex = "([a-zA-Z]+)"

df %>% 
 mutate(name = str_to_title(name)) %>% 
 extract(name, 
         into = "last_name", 
         my.regex, 
         remove = FALSE) %>%  
left_join( lookup_table)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   name                    last_name first_name middle_name
#>   <chr>                   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      
#> 1 Clinton                 Clinton   Hillary    Rodham     
#> 2 Clinton, Hillary Rodham Clinton   Hillary    Rodham     
#> 3 Clinton, Hillary        Clinton   Hillary    Rodham     
#> 4 Clinton, Hil            Clinton   Hillary    Rodham
```

This technique assures you of perfect data and is scalable.

Note: The regex above only extracts the last name from the examples given. Not sure whether/how you intend on discriminating between the candidates Bill/Hillary Clinton or Jeb/George/George Bush if given only a single name ("Bush", "Clinton").

Created on 2018-07-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).